# CORS header not set - can I request an image url and then serve it back to myself?

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest, cors, webgl

I am attempting to populate a WebGL Earth with meshes that are compiled from images. These images are cross-domain, and hosted on a server where setting the appropriate headers isn't an option. Can I XMLHttpRequest the image urls, and then serve them back to myself via PHP to bypass CORS errors?

Or, more specifically, can I use my own webserver as a proxy to serve img urls back to myself (to get around CORS) in a WebGL context?

**EDIT**: The real question here is if I can use my own webserver as a proxy to pass the urls, or if I'll have to actually download each image to the server to then use it.

Comment: if you mean "using your own webserver as a proxy to another one", yes you can !

Comment: @JuniusRendel Yes, that's what I mean. More specifically, can I use my own webserver as a proxy to serve img urls to myself (to get around CORS) in a WebGL context?

Comment: What you want to do is using pictures from another source and put them into WebGL Earth. Do you have an example to show us? And your problem is that you receive an error message that says something with CORS error. Is that in a Browser? What does the error say?

Comment: @hogan Yes, I want to use pictures from another source. The real question here is if I can use my own webserver as a proxy to pass the urls, or if I'll have to actually download each image to the server to then use it.

This is the error: "An error occured while accessing the tiles. Cross-domain access restrictions are applied on map tiles for WebGL. Either use CORS on remote domain (http://enable-cors.org/) or place your application on the same domain as tiles (hosting app and tiles on the same domain or running a tile proxy)."
 
As I said, enabling CORS on the remote domain isn't an option.

Comment: I wrote an answer already before another question popped up: What component do you want to use in WebGL Earth? Is it WE.tileLayerJSON()?

Comment: @hogan Yes, it's `WE.tileLayer(imgUrl, { bounds: [lat,long] });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue once using an API. First I tried to do everything in JS probably getting the same error message as you do.

My solution was to switch to PHP and do it server side since modern Browsers block what you want to do.

---

#### So yes, it is possible.

Get the pictures on the backend and then provide them to the frontend.

---

Simply retrieve the pictures first and then send them as Output to the Browser. You can do that synchronously by doing something like:

```
$ch = curl_init ... 
...
$pic = curl_exec ... // get the picture

// and then echo it
```

This I have done once but don't remember correctly. Or you can do it async, what is usually done when using img-tags. I'm not sure how it works with WebGL but should be similar:

- Download the pic to your filesystem
- then provide the URL to the browser.

It then depends on how big the images are, how long you need them, and the API whether you want to go this direction.

---

**Answer to first comment:**

Tricky. I don't have experience using WebGL Earth and whether it is possible to load data async via Ajax (look [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/use-jquerys-ajax-function/)) or if you use AngularJS (look [here](http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/consuming-external-services/requesting-json-data-with-ajax.html)) into it. You would need to try that one out. I'd especially look into the loading times.

There is a API-call like `http://example.com/api/get_image/65446` which downloads the picture, resizes it and then sends it to the browser.

What you would do in this case is:

- Send the 'normal' Page to the user
- Then there you look for the events for which you want to show pictures
- When the event happened use the API-call I just mentioned and add it to your page with the success handler. Again, how that can work with WebGL Earth is another question I can't answer.

And if you want to use that for mobile devices you need to think about the picture size. Since the screens are relatively small you should make the pics smaller first. But then, how long does it take to get the picture I guess this is the biggest challenge. Somebody who wants scrolls the globe would like to see the pictures immediately, not after 5 seconds (since I scrolled more probably)

**Think about whether you can prepare the download and resize first.** If you want to show only certain pictures, like 10.000 in total then I would do that. Then you don't need to think about loading times as much and when you delete which pictures. You should open another question for that topic and try first whether Ajax is possible.

Comment: Thanks, this is approximately what I want to do. Do you think this will work in instances where 10-50 images approx 200kb each need to be called? I've no experience using a temporary cache or PHP in this way. It's a dynamically generated mesh, so as a user scrolls around the globe, images will be called. Also, since your solution entails PHP, how am I going to call that dynamically after page load?

Comment: @John Doe, is your question answered?

Comment: Partially. Async API calls isn't the hard part - you can do it easily with normal js. I was asking if it's possible to dynamically (ie after page load) make an XML request and then download the returned img url to the webserver, and then pass the image to the browser - all after page load. If it's not possible to do this after page load, probably the only option is to request the entire globe's worth of images, which would be a huge amount of bandwidth.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean by 'after page load'. I think then answer of that was with the hint of listening to an event, i.e. the user scrolled to a specific location. And then call your script. Check whether that is possible in WebGL Earth.